# Permission Denied When Running Shell Script

Tags: server, 20.04, scripts, lts, chmod

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. When I run a shell script, I get the following error: `-bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied`. I've looked at a similar post on this forum and none of those answers solved the problem. My terminal input and output are below. If anyone can help, that'd be very appreciated.

```
wilsont@bzoit:/media/wilsont/disk$ chmod u+r+x install.sh
wilsont@bzoit:/media/wilsont/disk$ ./install.sh
-bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: What type of filesystem is `/media/wilsont/disk` and how is it mounted? Try moving `install.sh` to your home directory and running it from there.

Comment: When I try to move the file to home, I get the following error: `mv: cannot create regular file '/home/install.sh': Permission denied`. I'm using this command: `mv ./install.sh /home`

Comment: You probably want to move it to `/home/username`, not `/home`.

Comment: After I run it in home, this happens: https://pastebin.com/RzJfRQhe

Comment: ... a wifi driver dated `Novembor, 21 2011` is almost certainly of no use to you now

Answer (score 0):

The file system is probably mounted with noexec option. First identify the partition on which you're executing the script. You can do it using `mount` command. It'll give a you a list of all mounted partitions and their mount points. Then run this following command `sudo mount <partition_path> -o remount,rw,exec`. That will remount the partition with with read write and execute permissions set. Then try to execute the same script again.